# Convert standard Word equations to LaTeX

Tags: math-mode, word-to-latex

I have a Word document with a lot of formulas that I want to translate to LaTeX (actually it was a Powerpoint document but I extracted all the text to Word).

The most annoying task is to convert all the formulas to LaTeX style. Is there an easy way since MathType is something else than the built in formula editor. I could also copy-paste directly but for each math environment you have to set the `$`-symbols and edit more complex formulas such as fractions etc. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: Would this help? http://www.grindeq.com/index.php?p=word2latex

Comment: Is there nothing for free or a more "standardized" procedure/software?

Comment: I have used [word2tex](http://www.chikrii.com/ ) in the past and it worked nicely. Looking at the website, it appears that it has not been updated in a while so YMMV

Comment: Use the Toggle TeX option.

Comment: @JouleV: Where do you find this option? Is it built-in to Word?

Comment: @strpeter If you already install MathType to Word, you will see that option in the 'MathType' tab.

Comment: For free and good = manual. Trust me, it's one of my daily jobs and I invested some time into looking for options. Especially if the document is sort of messed up (which it probably is after conversion of whatever powerpoint stuff into word), tools will be failing miserably. But you might be more lucky than I ever was...

Comment: http://mathpix.com/ might help. This uses an AI to analyse a snapshot and generates TeX from this, works quite well!

Answer (score 2):

I would check out Pandoc at pandoc.org. This program can convert your files from Word to Tex. Install Pandoc to your system and run the following shell-command from the demo-site.

```
pandoc -s MANUAL.txt -o example29.docx
```

**UPDATE:**
The pandoc documentation can be found at
https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html
The above code goes from tex (latex, .txt) to a Microsoft word file instead of the other way around.

Entering the following in a bash terminal will convert to tex.
`pandoc -s -o "output_filename.tex" "input_filename.docx"`
The `-o` indicates the next argument will be the output filename. The `-s` indicates to create a standalone output file as opposed to just a fragment.

Comment: Excellent suggestion, thanks!
The syntax you quoted is used to convert _to_ Word though (not _from_ Word as requested, but that's easy too)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert **only** the equations to LaTeX form, there is already one button for you to do it: That is the "Toogle TeX" button in the MathType tab:

[image]

---

### This is an example:

Firstly I have this:

[image]

Choose the part you want to change, then click the button. (In my example, I choose the whole document):

[image]

This is a result after a while:

[image]

That's it! Though I am using Office 2019, this button still appears in lower versions of Office (at least to my old Office 2003).

> **Note:** Actually for almost a year I haven't used Word and MathType (I use LaTeX instead). So I haven't updated MathType for long. I have MathType 6 and I think the current version of MathType is probably MathType 7 (I'm not sure). Hope that the button still stands there in MathType 7.

Comment: I was looking "for free or a more "standardized" procedure/software" as I wrote above.

Comment: I don’t think MathType is part of base Word. This is an answer to a different question.